# Elliptic fibrations on the Fermat quartic surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-surfaces, k3-surfaces

Consider the Fermat quartic surface
$$
x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + t^4 = 0
$$
over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristics $p$, where $p \equiv 3$ ($\mathrm{mod}$ $4$).
Is there the **full** classification of elliptic fibrations (up to an isomorphism) on it? In particular, can you give examples of isotrivial elliptic fibrations (j-invariants are constants)?

Comment: For $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ this K3 surface is the "supersingular" surface
of Artin invariant $1$; elliptic fibrations correspond to even lattices 
of rank $20$ with $L^*/L \cong ({\bf Z}/p{\bf Z})^2$, which is a
"full classification" of sorts but the number of such lattices
grows rapidly with $p$ (there are $52$ for $p=3$, and I recently counted
$2683$ for $p=7$).

Comment: For isotrivial fibrations, there's at least $Y^2 = X^3 - (t^3-t)^2 X$,
or more generally $y^2 = Q(t)^3 P(x/Q(t))$ where $u^2 = P(t)$ and $u^2 = Q(t)$
are supersingular elliptic curves in characteristic $p$.  These K3 surfaces
must all be isomorphic with the Fermat quartic, because the $e=1$ surface 
is unique; but finding explicit isomorphisms can be tricky.